# Best way to make a function wait / block and then signal that function to continue from another function

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, flutter, asynchronous

I am busy building an app that uses MQTT as a communication channel. The data comes in on a stream in an async manner. So I want to use the MQTT in a 2-way communication manner. I am starting off by building the login dialog for a user. So what will happen is that the app will build the login dialog that has the username and password on, when the user clicks on login the app will send a command on a topic that the server is listening on and the the app needs to wait and not remove the login dialog and show a spinner to the user to show that the app is waiting. The app will receive its answer on another topic it is listening on that the server will send the result on.

So my question is this. What is the best way to have the login dialog block / wait until we get a message on the topic that the server will send. This data will come in a stream that is not part of the login call. I do have access to the data via Provider. And how do I then send a message to the blocking dialog to continue. All the example I see is with await on the call to an API. The API will return on the same call. In my case the API will not return as it is running async. I also want an timeout on the blocking / waiting login dialog should we not get a response from the server.

So I need to wait (how do I wait? Do I sit in a while loop with sleeps? Is there a better way?) until I get the data back on a topic and then continue on getting the data or a timeout. I do have the MQTT all working, just need to figure out the best way to wait / block and then pass the data to that wait / blocking function to tell it to continue.

Comment: Why are you doing all that? What is the point? Why not just run a normal network request, display a spinner and in the completion block / callback of the request dismiss the login dialog or show some error depending on the response!?

Comment: There is a reason for it. The server is an IOT device that sits inside a private network. So the app does not have direct access to it as it can be outside the network. The IOT device and the APP connects to a broker in the cloud. this all runs over MQTT. All is working accept I want to be able to signal a waiting function from the data that comes in. I do it all the time with multithreaded apps but as I am new to Flutter would like to know if there is a way to do it out of the box or should I build my own way.

Comment: OK so I have it working, just wondering if this is the best way. I have a while loop that checks data inside a Provider Model, it will then use the await Future delayed with 200 milliseconds every time to give the app time to process everything else it needs to do. Once the data comes in on the mqtt side it will update the data in the Provider model and then we proses it. I can also have a timeout in the while loop by having a counter. It all seems to be working. Just wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

So I have it working like this. Not sure if there is a better way but this works 100%

```
        //Update the result
        appState.loginResult = 'X';
        timeoutCounter = 0;

        //We sit in the loop until the data changes from X
        while (appState.loginResult == 'X') {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
          timeoutCounter++;
          if (timeoutCounter >= 25) {
            appState.loginResult = 'T';
          }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to the dialog inside your activity/fragment. You can keep it up just dont close it? Then whatever logic you have you can simply call the dialog in a way or another (via a callback or interface).